# How to hide a div moving from one menu to another menu using angular js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular js, I do not know much, by making R&D, I am doing .
Here in my project I have 7 menu .Here in home page there is a banner ,which will be shown only in home page .
While shifting from home page menu to other menu ,i want to hide that banner for other pages .
I have done some thing like ,its working partially ,i.e when i am refreshing the page in other menus ,banner is not showing .That's fine ,but i just need to hide banner when i am clicking from one menu to other .

Below i have attached some of my code.Please have a look.

```html
function MainController($scope, $location) {

    var pId = $location.path().split("/")[1] || "Unknown";
    // alert(pId);
    if (pId == "homepage")
    {
        $scope.b = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.b = false;
    }
}
```

This is my maincontroller

```
function HomeController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.b = true;
//my other codes
}
```

This is my home page controller ,where i want to show the banner

```
function AboutUsController($scope, $http) {
     $scope.b = false;
     //my other codes
}
```

This is about us controller i.e about us page/menu.Here i want to hide the banner ,when i am switching from home to about us menu.

And in banner html page my code is below

```
<div class="banner" ng-show="b">
    <ul class="mySlideshow">
        <li><img src="banner1.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="banner2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="banner3.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]
 This is what i have tried ,where i am doing wrong?
Please 
suggest .Thank you.

Comment: We need to see more of your HTML structure. We cannot see the controller hierarchy, which is important to solving your issue. Show the `ng-controller` section if it exists.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle Ok i will surely provide you